# How to handle windows pop up from Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

My scenario is like after login user name, password, and logon.have to see the next screen. but after logon there in window pop saying that you logged in successfully. i dont know how to handle it?

Comment: Welcome at [so]. It is expected that questions meet certain criteria. These are described in the [ask] page that I strongly suggest you read. In addition we expect a certain level of effort to already have been spent on your part. This is typically done by showing us the code that you're working on and providing us with descriptions of the things you've tried and the results you've observed. In case of larger blocks of code, simplifying it to a [mcve] helps to understand the issue much quicker on our part.

Answer (score 1):

please use this keyword:    Handle Alert

You don't need to pass any argument, it will accept confirmation box.